# Why isn't there a way to label a column as "keyword"

Tags: schema, rdbms

In a typical star schema, you end up with a bunch of columns that are an ID into some lookup table, where the lookup table is pretty much just this:

`create table hostnames ( 
  id primary key, 
  name varchar(200)
)`

And when you select from your main table, you end up with a bunch of left joins, when you insert, you always have to lookup for the ID first, then insert if it's not there. It's a pain. 50% of my database related code is just for dealing with this.

It would be nice to have a way to indicate to the database that a given column has low number of distinct values, so that it can build its own internal lookup table and save space. The above would become:

```
create table sometablewithahostname (
    ...
    hostname varchar(200) keyword,
    ...
)
```

And there is no need to manage a the other tables.
Is there a RDBMS system that does that?

Comment: Column-oriented systems do that. Example: [Infobright](http://www.infobright.com/Products/Compression/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to de-normalize while mitigating the storage space requirements, [Hybrid Column Compression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT89202) in Oracle 11gR2 can help with this.  It is only available on Enterprise Edition [with a few specific types of storage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e10594/editions.htm#DBLIC2152).

> Storing column data together, with the same data type and similar
>   characteristics, dramatically increases the storage savings achieved
>   from compression. The database compresses data manipulated by any SQL
>   operation, although compression levels are higher for direct path
>   loads. Database operations work transparently against compressed
>   objects, so no application changes are required.